# Pairs of numbers in columns of an increasing matrix

Tags: co.combinatorics

Let $A$ be a $n$x$n$ matrix with entries $a_{i,j}$ in {$1,2,\cdots ,m$} such that $a_{i+1,j} > a_{i,j}$ and $a_{i,j+1} > a_{i,j}.$ If m is $o(n^2),$ then for sufficiently large $n$ must there exist two integers $p,q$ such that there exist at least three columns containing both $p$ and $q$?

This question is a continuation of [Family of subsets such that there are at most two sets containing two given elements](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/92203/family-of-subsets-such-that-there-are-at-most-two-sets-containing-two-given-eleme). I realized that my problem suggested this condition as a very natural restriction on the sets, but I can't see how to work with the condition.